# Magento2 Fatal error on Cart Page

Tags: magento2

I am using custom theme inherted by blank theme.
I updated magento2 from 2.1.0 to 2.1.2 through composer and after update i am getting following error on cart page.

> Fatal error: Class 'Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Block' not found in D:\wamp\www\mysite\vendor\magento\module-wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Wishlist.php on line 12

Answer (score 0):

In terminal go to your project path run this three command one by one.Your Problem may solved thereafter.

```
project-path> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
project-path> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
project-path> chmod -R 777 var
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer.
I've already tried these commands but problem still not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `generation` and `di` folder:

**Root Path:**

shop_root/var/generation

shop_root/var/di

Delete folder via FTP or terminal comments. Please refer below mentioned comments.

```
shop-path> rm -rf var/generation

shop-path> rm -rf var/di
```

Execute this comments, after flush the shop cache.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried that every basic things before posting my question.